# How to manage images for a mobile app

Tags: javascript, image, mobile

I am jumping from Core Java/OSGi into the mobile space, for my initial project I am putting together a little Cordova / Famous / Angular app.  I would like to display an image that fills the top half of the screen (100% width x 50% height) and then use a lightbox that transitions between images.

**I am having a hard time finding resources that describe best practices for managing image resources.**
  Some of my questions include:

- My assumption is you want to standardize your images to a certain size and target density.  What are the size x density combinations I should be targeting?
- Since this will be a background image, is it better to use a `<span>` and set the background-image attribute or use an `<img>`?
- How does the above choice of tag change if I wanted to have a mirrored effect?  Should I stick to the `<img>` and set webkit-box-reflect or use another `<span>` combined with some rotation?

The idea is to fill the space, which will mean that on some devices either the horizontal or vertical edges may not be visible. Ultimately, I know the best answer will be finding something that works and just sticking with that.

**What are some reliable resources that describe best practices for image management, specifically related to managing images for mobile devices?**

Thanks,

JD

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources out there. You can easily find many Videos, tutorials, articles etc.

I suggest to start with following. They cover almost all aspects including graphics, performance, quality of an intuitive app.

**Apple iOS**

Learn how to build the polished, engaging, and intuitive apps that Apple customers expect

- https://developer.apple.com/design/
- https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/

**Android**

Design and build apps the right way. Learn how to create apps that look great and perform well on as many devices as possible, from phones to tablets and more.

- http://developer.android.com/design/index.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/index.html

**IBM Mobile Solutions Best Practices**

Starting a new mobile development project? These best practices are general in scope and can help you plan your app's architecture and progress through front-end development. (These practices are not specific to any particular Worklight release.)

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/best-practices.html

**See Images related [Tips](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/bestpractices/FrontEndDevelopment/Images.pdf).**

**Blackberry**

When you follow best practices, you can improve the performance of your app and make it easier to debug and maintain.

- http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_2/best_practices_for_web_development.html

**Windows Mobile Apps**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994633.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202944(v=vs.105).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677125.aspx

**Update:**

**Image optimization**

There is another great source on Google Developers site and is specific to Image Optimization.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

- Eliminating and replacing images
- Vector vs. Raster images
- Implications of high-resolution screens
- Optimizing vector images
- Optimizing raster images
- Lossless vs lossy image compression
- Selecting the right image format
- Tools and parameter tuning
- Delivering scaled image assets
- Image optimization checklist

Hope this should help.